# How to configure EF Core 7 OwnsMany to delete multiple child entities with a single SQL statement?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an entity class called **WatchCategoryEntity** which has a collection property _watchCategorySymbols of type **List**. I'm using Entity Framework Core to interact with my SQL Server database, and I'm trying to delete a range of **WatchCategorySymbolEntity** objects from this collection using the **RemoveRange** method.

Currently, when I call **dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync()** after deleting the items using RemoveRange, EF Core generates multiple separate **DELETE** statements in the SQL query, instead of a single **DELETE ... IN** statement.

Here's what my current **DeleteSymbolRange** method looks like:

```
public void DeleteSymbolRange(IEnumerable<string> symbolIsins)
{
    _watchCategorySymbols.RemoveAll(s => symbolIsins.Contains(s.SymbolIsin));
    ClearDomainEvents();
    AddDomainEvent(new ShardEntityDeletedDomainEvent(this));
}
```

And here's my **WatchCategoryConfig**:

```
internal sealed class WatchCategoryConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<WatchCategoryEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<WatchCategoryEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnType("char(32)");
        builder.Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnType("nvarchar").IsUnicode().HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(p => p.Order).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Property(p => p.IsDefault).IsRequired();
        builder.OwnsMany(p => p.WatchCategorySymbols,
            b =>
            {
                b.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("WatchCategoryId");
                b.ToTable("WatchCategorySymbols");
                b.Property("Id").HasColumnType("bigint");
                b.Property(i => i.SymbolIsin).HasMaxLength(12);
            });

        var navigation = builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(WatchCategoryEntity.WatchCategorySymbols));
        navigation.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}
```

I'm calling **SaveChangesAsync()** after deleting the items like this:

```
await dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

How can I modify my **DeleteSymbolRange** method to use a single **DELETE ... IN** statement instead of multiple separate **DELETE** statements? Or is there another approach I should be taking to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With EF Core 7 `ExecuteDelete` - `dbcontext.WatchCategorySymbols.Where(s => symbolIsins.Contains(s.SymbolIsin)).ExecuteDelete();`

Comment: I only have WatchCategories in my DbContext wich is the aggregate root of WatchCategorySymbols in its configuration.

Comment: Then you can't do that. Or change something in your architecture, performance needs tradeoff.

Comment: You should possibly be able to then just use `dbContext.Set<WatchCategorySymbol>().Where(s => symbolIsIns.Contains(s.SymbolIsIn)).ExecuteDelete();`  Otherwise perhaps consider using an explicit `ExecuteSql` call for that scenario to optimize the operation.